# Matlab: Draw Streamline in quiver plot

Tags: matlab

In Matlab, I want to draw a streamline within a quiver plot. That is, I start with

```
quiver(X,Y,u,v)
```

where X, Y, u ,v are  of size 198 x 1.

Now, I want to draw a streamline starting at X(1) and Y(1), i.e. I wrote

```
hold on;
streamline(X,Y,u,v,X(1),Y(1))
```

But this does not work. I get the error message

```
Error using stream2 (line 46)
U,V must all be size 2x2 or greater.
Error in streamline (line 62)
      verts = stream2(x,y,u,v,sx,sy,options);

Error in computation (line 261)
streamline(X,Y,u,v,X(1),Y(1))
```

Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

streamline is expecting data for a full vector field and anticipates doing some interpolation to draw an arbitrary streamline within that field.  See [the documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/streamline.html).

If all you want to do is draw a single streamline that follows the points given in X and Y you can just use plot or line to create it.

If X and Y are just points scattered throughout your domain where you have data, you need to restructure it into the format that streamline expects (the output from meshgrid).  You can get to that from your scattered data using [scatteredinterpolant](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/scatteredinterpolant.html).

Comment: quiver gives me the "phase plane" (which here is plotting Y vs. X and then, at each point (X,Y) the arrow of the derivative. Then I want to draw the line starting at the point (X(1),Y(1)) and indicated by the arrows. I do not need streamline for the latter?

Comment: If you just want a curve that passes through (X(1),Y(1)), (X(2),Y(2)), ... you don't need streamline for that.  plot(X,Y) will do that.